# How do i get the correct total character count?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently trying to write a function in Excel that generates a report in Word. The function will involve multiple iterations within it as it tries to solve a particular problem. I, however, need to make tables for each iteration. I have tried to place the tables by using the start and end of the range as the total number of characters. However, after isolating the problem it seems that the `Compute` statistics function returns the number of words instead of characters.

How do I get the correct total character count?

Here is an example of a part of my code.

```
Function Asci()

     Dim objWord
     Dim objDoc
     Dim objSelection
     Dim a(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double

     Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
     objWord.Visible = True
     Set objSelection = objWord.Selection         

    for x = 1 to 3            
      objSelection.TypeText (qq & " Some text ------- " & q & Chr(11))                           
      a(1, 1) = 1
      a(1, 2) = 2
      a(2, 1) = 3
      a(2, 2) = 4

      charCount = objWord.ActiveDocument.Range.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces)                       
      Set myRange = objWord.ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=charCount, End:=charCount)
      objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2
      objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(x).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Element"
      objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(x).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Effective Length"
      objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(x).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Distance"
      objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(x).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "Moment of Inertia"
      Next       
    End Function
```

When isolating the problem

```
    Function Asci()

      Dim objWord
      Dim objDoc
      Dim objSelection

      Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

      objWord.Visible = True

      Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

      objSelection.TypeText (" Some text ------" & Chr(11))

      charCount = objWord.ActiveDocument.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces)
      objSelection.TypeText ("count " & charCount)
      objDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Save")
    End Function
```

I get the number of words rather than the number of characters.

Comment: Welcome!  Your question is very unclear, although when I ran your code it gave the **correct** number of characters (except of course that printing that count in the directly in the document itself *changes the number of characters* in the document.)  Before I attempt to interpret what you're trying to do, what the issue is, and what your expected result is, please check out the [tour] and well as [ask] and special attention to [mcve], and then [edit] your question to add more information?

Comment: I hope the question is clearer now. Thank you.